# Connecting an Android Device with a BLE Peripheral without using an App

Tags: android, node.js, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-peripheral

I am new to Android programming and was wondering if it was possible to connect an Android device with a BLE Peripheral, without needing an App.

I am experimenting with the Node.js package "bleno" for the peripheral and connecting using an app and even a webapp are working just fine, but connecting using the standard android settings functions dont work. The device does find my peripheral after scanning but when I try to connect with it it always returns that I need an app.

Is this a problem of bleno or does this not work that way in generell?

Answer (score 2):

If the peripheral has for example a HID GATT service exposed, then you can pair and connect to it through the system settings. This means BLE keyboards and mice can be used without any app.

If your peripheral only has custom services or only services the OS knows nothing about, then you will need some app to connect to it.